# How to fill a 2D matrix with a list of characters?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create a program in which every letter in the alphabet corresponds to a number (i.e. a = 0, b = 1, ...etc.). When a letter is inputted, a 4 x 4 matrix fills up with it's corresponding number (i.e. abcdef... = [[0,1,2,3],[4, 5..]).

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import re
tthMatrix = np.zeros((4,4))

text = "I leave twenty million dollars to my friendly cousin Bill"

pat = re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z ]+')
str = re.sub(pat, '', text).lower()
textSplit = str.split()

def switch_function(textSplit):
print(text)
print(textSplit)
for word in textSplit:
        for char in word:

            switcher = {
                    "a": np.insert(tthMatrix, 0, 0),
                    "b": np.insert(tthMatrix, 1, 1),
                    "c": np.insert(tthMatrix, 2, 2),
                    "d": np.insert(tthMatrix, 3, 3),
                    "e": np.append(tthMatrix, 4),
                    "f": np.append(tthMatrix, 5),
                    "g": np.append(tthMatrix, 6),
                    "h": np.append(tthMatrix, 7),
                    "i": np.append(tthMatrix, 8),
                    "j": np.append(tthMatrix, 9),
                    "k": np.append(tthMatrix, 10),
                    "l": np.append(tthMatrix, 11),
                    "m": np.append(tthMatrix, 12),
                    "n": np.append(tthMatrix, 13),
                    "o": np.append(tthMatrix, 14),
                    "p": np.append(tthMatrix, 15),
                    "q": np.append(tthMatrix, 16),
                    "r": np.append(tthMatrix, 17),
                    "s": np.append(tthMatrix, 18),
                    "t": np.append(tthMatrix, 19),
                    "u": np.append(tthMatrix, 20),
                    "v": np.append(tthMatrix, 21),
                    "w": np.append(tthMatrix, 22),
                    "x": np.append(tthMatrix, 23),
                    "y": np.append(tthMatrix, 24),
                    "z": np.append(tthMatrix, 25)
                    }
            print(switcher.get(char, "no match"))
            print("\n")

switch_function(textSplit)
```

When new letters get inserted, the previous number just gets replaced, and I end up with this output:

```
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 8.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 11.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 4.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 21.]
```

and so on. How can I get the matrix to fill in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly. If so, this algorithm should work:

```
import numpy as np


def letter_to_number(char):
    return ord(char.upper()) - 65


def convert_stringseq_to_matrix(stringseq):
    result = np.zeros((4, 4))
    stringseq = stringseq.replace(" ", "")

    for index, character in enumerate(stringseq):
        if index >= 16:
            break

        x = int(index / 4)
        y = index % 4

        number = letter_to_number(character)
        result[x][y] = number

    return result


print(convert_stringseq_to_matrix("abcdef"))
print(convert_stringseq_to_matrix("za"))
```

The output looks like:

```
[[0. 1. 2. 3.]
 [4. 5. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]

[[25.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, the only problem is getting rid of spaces but I appreciate the help!

Comment: I added the line stringseq = stringseq.replace(" ", ""). This should do the trick.